# How to develop chat application (text) using Flash Media Server + Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, adobe-media-server

I have developed a Virtual Class Room, I'm done with Live Class with Video Streaming using Adobe Media Server.
Now I want to add a small chat window in that session so that If someone having any kind of problem they can text me on that chat window.
    I don't have any Idea how to stream a text file to Server.
From where should I start??
Give me some Important link also...

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [SmartFoxServer](http://www.smartfoxserver.com), they have a complete solution and also [some examples](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/download/get/108), that you can use to study and guide your own implementation. Also a robust [documentation](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesFlash/introduction).